GA4 how do I create a report that shows an event count of all cars filtered by colour to show only a count of total times the colour was chosen?
In GA4 I have a url that shows the make of car and the colour selected in a filter on teh left of the page. I need to create a report that shows how many times each colour was ticked. A total for each colour.
Tried a filter for a ebent count on Page Path and query string filtered for contains &colour but all I get is a list of url's with colour in them.  I need to create a report, table and chart that shows each colour selected with a total event count for each colour
